# Delegate method privately called from delegate itself?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

One has established design patterns so ingrained in their brain, that when sometimes somebody does something unexpected, it is a revelation.

My colleague in an iOS project did call the delegate method from the delegate class itself. That means the delegator was not involved in invoking this method at all.

Does this break some kind of principle or design pattern? Technically the delegate method is just like any other method and it is available in the class to call. But we are used to only delegators calling them.

Is he breaking a promise of some kind?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator

Comment: I tried hard, I swear, but I couldn't find an analogy or insight in the article from your link.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/236205/delegate-method-privately-called-from-delegate-itself) will help

Comment: But this case is not recursion afaik.

It's about expecting that only one particular class will call my method..and instead I am calling the method myself.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: That Wikipedia is math, man.  Us poor bastards who don't know all the maths need a little help with that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You basically just pass your recursive function as a parameter to itself

Comment: A short code example would greatly improve this question.